# Poisson regression to find the busiest hour at an ice cream shop

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

If I wanted to find the busiest hour at an ice cream shop and I had the counts of the type of ice cream sold per hour per day. Could I use Poisson regression to find the busiest hour and month etc for the shop?

Or would it only work if I had a unique identifier for each individual, and looked at it at an individual level. I.e. someone is twice as likely to buy ice cream at 7pm than 2am?

Thank you

Comment: you could, but what is insufficient about looking at the average count of ice cream sold per hour, and seeing which hour has the highest value? Also, why does uniqueness of customers matter to you? From a revenue and labor perspective, it's not obvious to me if it matters if there's 1000 different people buying 2 scoops of ice cream each, or just one person coming in 1000 times throughout the day.

Comment: Thanks for your help John. It is a theoretical question - I don't have an ice cream shop unfortunately :( I was thinking Poisson regression as sales might vary over time due to Summer etc.  Regarding the uniqueness - all the examples I have saw have been about an individual doing something. I wanted the focus to be on a business for example. Does that make sense?

Comment: "I was thinking Poisson regression as sales might vary over time due to Summer etc" Ah OK! Now we're talking. We could indeed use a Poisson regression to figure out the various seasonalities/one-off events involved and try to decompose them. Most of this kind of stuff is covered in Time Series textbooks, typically in the context of OLS. (but it almost all carries over directly to count models).

Comment: Thanks John. If I ever open an ice cream shop you can have free ice cream for life! Have you ever came across Poisson regression not being done at an individual level? As I said, all the examples I have seen have been about individuals doing something

Comment: Can you show us some of the examples you mean? One of the core properties of Poisson processes is that we can aggregate as far as we like and still have Poisson stuff going on, so I'm tempted to say you can drop your concern. (But if we're going to be very precise, it's true that we may wish to model purchases from the same individual as being correlated, and the aggregated process would no longer be Poisson. But I expect the average ice cream parlor not to worry about this kind of thing).

Comment: Thanks. So I could possibly aggregate by the type of ice cream bought? So for example to predict and model how often someone will get a haircut in a year, as opposed to using modelling to look at the relationship between variables and the number of haircuts a hairdresser performs?

Comment: I was referring to aggregation over individuals. What I meant was that if each individual has a Poisson process representing their ice cream purchasing habits, the sum of all your hypothetical clients' purchases will also be poisson, with the intensity given by the sum of the clients' intensities. (making some unrealistic but ubiquitous assumptions like independence of each client's purchases *between* clients). But yeah this same logic applies to aggregating over ice cream flavors.

Comment: If you are mainly interested in forecasting, then [this may be interesting](https://dfep.netlify.app/sec-multiple-seasaonality). No Poisson regression there, but there is nothing to keep you from using that instead of the plain vanilla regression there. (And now I see the figures are missing. Sigh...)

Comment: What do you mean by "hour" Do you mean 60 minute increment? or integral hour?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary at all to parametrize an *individual's* ice cream buying intensity, nor is it even necessary to invoke Poisson as a probability model at all. Just use a box car filter to estimate the maximum hour of sales using the daily time series data.

Comment: @AdamO Interesting, I'll look into that. Thanks

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for your input. I will look at this

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks. However, I'm not sure what you mean by intensities?

Comment: @Randomname if you're not familiar with the Poisson Process we can stick to Poisson Distributions, and you just have to sub in "rate parameter" whenever you see me write "intensity".

Comment: @JohnMadden I'm familiar with Poisson modelling. I have never heard of 'intensity' before. Just to make sure, I understand you. So I can use the Poisson regression to look at the hour the most ice cream is sold in the shop? As opposed to looking at variables of an individual, and how much ice cream they buy? Thanks

Comment: @Randomname yes that's right